# Convolution: generating a continuous-time signal from a discrete-time sequence

Tags: filters, discrete-signals, convolution, continuous-signals

Given a discrete-time (DT) sequence $g[n]$, I want to represent it as a continuous-time (CT) signal. I can do this by representing this sequence as a weighted sum of Dirac delta impulses. Would it make a difference if I pass the DT signal through a DT filter first and then represent it as a weighted sum of Dirac impulses or pass the CT signal through a CT filter. The two cases are as follows:

**Case 1**: DT sequence converted first to CT signal and passed through CT filter.

The DT signal can be represented as a CT signal as:
$$g(t)=\sum_kg[k]\delta(t-kT)\tag{1}$$
If $g(t)$ in $(1)$ is the input to a continuous-time LTI system with impulse response $h(t)$, the output is given by
$$y(t)=\int h(\tau)g(t-\tau)d\tau = \int h(\tau)\left(\sum_kg[k]\delta(t-\tau-kT)\right)d\tau$$
or
$$y(t) =\sum_kg[k]\int h(\tau)\delta(t-\tau-kT) d\tau$$
or
$$y(t) = \sum_kg[k]h(t-kT)\tag{2}$$

**Case 2**: DT sequence passed through DT filter and then converted first to CT signal.

The DT signal is passed through a DT filter $h[n] = h(nT)$ to obtain a DT signal $z[n]$:
$$z[n]=\sum_kg[k]h[n-k]\tag{3}$$
This can be represented as a CT signal as
$$z(t)=\sum_kz[k]\delta(t-kT)\tag{4}$$

Is $z(t)$ same as $y(t)$? Can I express one in terms of the other? Any help wuld be greatly appreciated?
-ryan

Comment: Your equation (2) is not accurate. You have to use a convolution integral, not a sum.

Comment: @Jazzmaniac Thanks forthe response. If I use the convolution integral, wouldn't it still evaluate to a sum as g(t) is expressed as a sum?

Comment: @Jazzmaniac I edited the question to explain equation (2).

Comment: The two cases can never be the same because in the first case you end up with a weighted sum of CT impulse responses, whereas in the second case you still have a discrete-time signal, which becomes a weighted sum of Dirac impulses, but which remains zero between the sample points.

Comment: @MattL.: Ok, I see the difference now. Yes, they can't be the same. But if you see my derivation in my answer, why it "seems" to hold true. What is incorrect there?

Comment: Your last formula preceded by "or" is wrong, because in the line above you still just have weighted Dirac impulses, and by some magic they are transformed into shifted continuous-time functions $h(t-lT)$, but that's not the case. A discrete-time signal without continuous-time filtering applied to it, will always remain a discrete-time signal. You can represent it by a weighted Dirac comb, but this doesn't change the fact that there's nothing in between sample points.

Answer (score 1):

I believe (2) and (4) are same. One can write $z(t)$ as

$$z(t) = \sum_k z[k]\delta(t-kT) = \sum_k \left(\sum_l g[l]h[k-l]\right)\delta(t-kT)$$

But $h[k-l] = h((k-l)T)$. Thus,
$$z(t) = \sum_l g[l] \left(\sum_k h((k-l)T) \delta(t-kT) \right) = \sum_l g[l] \left(\sum_k h(kT-lT) \delta(t-kT) \right) $$
or
$$z(t) = \sum_l g[l] h(t-lT)$$
which, by change of variables, is same as (2).